# Unable to add image to Outlook Online

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I want to add an image to my mail body by Office.js but this is not working for Outlook Online.
I don't want my picture to be accessible for everyone so this is what I do (this works for Outlook Desktop):

**Add an attachment by url**

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(url, name,
            { isInline: true }, 
            function (asyncResult) {
                ...
            });
```

**Add image to body**

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync('<img src="cid:' + name + '">',
                { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, 
                function (asyncResult) {
                });
```

After the file is attached we remove the image so it isn't available anymore at the url.
How do I get adding file attachments to work for Outlook Online?

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue.Are you invoking setSelectedDataAsync inside the callback for addFileAttachmentAsync?

Comment: Yes I am. The issue is only happening in Outlook Online. It gives an Mixed content warning, maybe that has to do with it?

Comment: Could you share a simple manifest that reproduces this issue so we can test on our end?

Comment: I tried making a very simple app, but got it working in there. I have to further investigate why it isn't in our app which is much more complex. Will let you know

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your issue, the recipients, as well as yourself is not able to see the photo that you've embedded on a email. Am I correct? The following are the possible reasons affecting the issue:

- Possible that the file size of the picture maybe too large
- A possible issue on recipients's end (browser issue)
- Slow nternet connection

For more information, please refer to the link below:[Unable to insert a photo in Outlook.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/unable-to-insert-a-photo-in-outlookcom/72609a70-a62e-411b-a112-ef7f2cb02ad7)

Hopefully it helps you!

Comment: I am able to manually send pictures with outlook, but it is not working using officejs. None of the things you mention is the case